# Identifier 'X' is not defined. 'Y' does not contain such a member

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I have the following interface and I can pass its parameter values to the base component. However, although I could pass string values without any problem, I cannot pass boolean values and encounter *"Identifier 'isDisabled' is not defined. 'CustomButton' does not contain such a member"* error.

```
export interface CustomButton {
    name: string;
    operation: string;
    tooltip: string;
    isDisabled?: boolean;
}
```

On the other hand, I set the default value of `isDisabled` in a component from that I call the base component:

```
buttons: CustomButton[];
isEmployeeDisabled = false; // set the value while defining variable

this.buttons = [
  {
    name: 'edit',
    tooltip: 'Edit Employee',
    operation: 'Delete',
    isDisabled: this.isEmployeeDisabled
    // isDisabled: true // if I use like this, it works fine but still gives that error
  }
];
```

I could not find why isDisabled is not known property. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: this.buttons: CustomButton[] = [...], try this and see if the ide gives you errors or warnings

Comment: Thanks Jack, but I already use `buttons: CustomButton[];` definition as I added to the question. So, I cannot use it as you mentioned as it is already defined like that. Any other idea?

Comment: The problem seems to be related to boolean type, because there is no porblem with the other types while using them in the same manner.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I recreated your scenario and i get no errors, which version of ionic are you using?

Comment: What do you mean with ionic? I use Angular 10+

Comment: I'm using Angular 10+ and the only error i'm getting is that 'operation' is not included inside CustomButton interface and it makes sense. Having 3 years of experience in Angular I don't know how to help you. Is it an ide error or this error doesn't make you compile the application?

Comment: It is just an IDE error.

Comment: You can use // @ts-ignore for making the error disapper. It still makes no sense to me, your code is fine. Add it one line up where you get the error.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure if it is just a tslint error. On the other hand, the error is on html page and I am not sure if I can suppress it by `// @ts-ignore `

Comment: @JackyShows Any idea amigo?

Answer (score 0):

Trying with Stackblitz in hand gives me this error:

```
Type '{name: string; tooltip: string; operation: string; isDisabled: boolean; } 'is not assignable to type' CustomButton '.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'operation' does not exist in type 'CustomButton'.
```

The problem is that the `operation` property in the `interface` is missing.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngclass-off-props?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I removed some lines for clarity and actually operation property is in the interface, not missing. Any idea related to the problem?